# Retrieve the data for all previous months of the same year except today's date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need help in writing the query to get the data for all previous months of the same year.

If today's date is July 20 2017, I need to retrieve the data for all previous months of the same year except today's date(July 20 2017).

If date is July 20 2017, data should consists of January'17 till 19 July 2017 and so on.

If date is July 21 2017, data should consists of January'17 till 20 July 2017

Thanks

Comment: We would love to help but first you need to show us what you've already tried. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: I have tried this

Comment: To get the current day at 00:00:00 hours you can just cast to `DATE` datatype (removing the time) and cast back to `DATETIME` if necessary `CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME)`. Other than that you need to provide an [MCVE] for us to help you.

Comment: select DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, 0, getdate())),
DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))  .. But this reteriving data only the current month and also it is not excluding the current date

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    dateCol >= DATEADD(yy,  DATEDIFF(yy,  0, GETDATE()), 0) AND
    dateCol < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

## Demo

Comment: It is not retrieving data for 19th July 2017. It is giving data till 18th July 2017

Comment: @SwatiJain Check the demo, my query should be working for you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen OP's column is probably datetime, and has time part which your query would eliminate for last day. You can add one more day on right side and replace between with >= and <

Comment: @NenadZivkovic I think I get it...thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing code its difficult but something like this in the where clause ....

```
WITH DATES AS (
SELECT GETDATE() AS MYDATE
UNION
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'01/01/1999 12:00:00.000')
UNION
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'01/02/2016 12:00:00.000')
UNION
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'01/04/2007 12:00:00.000')
UNION
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'01/05/2005 12:00:00.000')
UNION
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'01/05/2017 12:00:00.000')
UNION
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'01/01/2017 14:00:00.000')
)
SELECT * FROM DATES
WHERE 
CONVERT(DATE,DATES.MYDATE) < CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
AND 
DATEPART(YEAR,DATES.MYDATE) = DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a question how to get January 1st of current year, and how to get yesterday. There are various ways of doing it. One of the ways is below and other answers with different ideas are also fine.

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
WHERE YourDateCol >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),1,1)
AND YourDateCol < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

For yesterday, you actually take today at 0:00 and get everything before that.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in an efficient way, place two variables which will contain first day of the year and today's date.

```
DECLARE @firstDayOfYear as DateTime;
DECLARE @today as DateTime;

SET @firstDayOfYear = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),1,1);
SET @today = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);

SELECT * FROM [table]
WHERE [dateColumnToCompare] >= @firstDayOfYear
AND [dateColumnToCompare] < @today;
```